# Why my function is not deleting all strings from array?? javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this  array"

```
var text = [ 1,2,"a","etf",5,"9f",12,"laks"];
```

I  also  have  this  function that  will  iterate  through  the  text[]  and remove  strings. It  will  display only  numbers:

```
var isNumber = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i<text.length; i++){
        if(isNaN(text[i])){
            text.splice(i,1);          
        }
    }
    return text;
}
isNumber();
```

When i run it,  it  deletes some  of  strings,  not all  of  them... Any  idea??
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing items from the array while you're looping through it. Try this:

```
var isNumber = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
        if(isNaN(text[i])){
            text.splice(i, 1);
            i--; // go back one step so we won't skip the item after
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Or just use `Array.filter`

Comment: Great, this was quick. Thank you, it worked perfectly!

Comment: @pvg this to stay in the context of OP request. Plus `filter` return another array. What OP is trying to do is change the array itself!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir fair enough but the context of the question is also 'poster is relatively new at this'. Idiomatic answer is worth including.

Answer (score 1):

If you can run ES6, the following is far simpler

```
return text.filter(t => !isNaN(t));
```

There is also Number.isInteger, which would be preferred over isNaN and it's simple to polyfill if you need to.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to filter Strings you could use typeof with a filter

```
text = text.filter(function(item){
  return typeof item !== 'string';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use filter to return all value that are number.

Example Snippet:

```js
var text = [1, 2, "a", "etf", 5, "9f", 12, "laks"];

function isNumber(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(value) {
    return !isNaN(value)
  })
}

console.log(isNumber(text))
```